# Print several arrays via formatted print

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, printing

I have two different arrays

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [5, 6, 7]
```

and I want to print these arrays in one line like:

```
1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 5.00000 6.00000 7.00000
```

How do I accomplish that with a `*` or `**` operator? I always obtain a `SyntaxError`.

Command should look somehow like this:

```
print "%.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f" % (*A, *B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`%` operator - string formatting operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) can accept a tuple as a argument:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> B = [5,6,7]
>>> "%.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f %.5f" % tuple(A + B)
'1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 5.00000 6.00000 7.00000'
```